# Get Dataset Values from Chart JS onHover in Version 3

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Chart JS version 3.5.1, and I can't get the `onHover` function to work. My goal is to have the user hover or a data point, and then have the dataset values available to me inside the `onHover`.

Here's my setup:

```
var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')

var options = {
  onHover: function(evt) {
    console.log(evt)
    
    var item = myChart.getElementAtEvent(evt)
    console.log(item)
  },
  interaction: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    }
  },
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false
}

var myChart = new Chart(context, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: obj.labels,
    datasets: [...]
  },
  options: options
})
```

I'm getting and error on this line:

```
var item = myChart.getElementAtEvent(evt)
```

The error says:

> `myChart.getElementAtEvent is not a function`

I have confirmed that `myChart` is an object, but there doesn't appear to be a `getElementAtEvent` function.

I also tried the example [in the docs here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#converting-events-to-data-values):

```
const canvasPosition = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(e, chart);

// Substitute the appropriate scale IDs
const dataX = chart.scales.x.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.x);
const dataY = chart.scales.y.getValueForPixel(canvasPosition.y);
```

But it says:

> `Cannot read property 'getValueForPixel' of undefined`

Does anyone know how I can successfully use `onHover` with version `3.5.1` of Chart JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using chart.js v3, in v3 there is no `getElementAtEvent`, it has been replaced with [`getElementsAtEventForMode`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/api.html#getelementsateventformode-e-mode-options-usefinalposition). You can use this to get the active elements but you can also use the second argument the `onHover` function recieves which is an array with all the active elements:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    onHover: (evt, activeEls, chart) => {
      if (activeEls.length === 0 || chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', {
          intersect: true
        }, true).length === 0) {
        return;
      }

      console.log('Function param: ', activeEls[0].index);
      console.log('lookup with the event: ', chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', {
        intersect: true
      }, true)[0].index);

      activeEls.forEach(point => {
        console.log('val: ', chart.data.datasets[point.datasetIndex].data[point.index])
      })
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!